# Does this company use Rackspace as their host?

Tags: networking, dns

I have a homework assignment to explain how DNS resolves for the address www.bcu.org.uk.
I have ran an nslookup and got NS records for this address to be cloudflare, with A records pointing to cloudflare servers.
However when getting the A record for the domain "BCU.org.uk" without www, I get an IP address of a Rackspace server. Does this mean the company host with rackspace? or could this just be an old A record?

could anyone possible have a look at this for me?

regards

Steve

Comment: I don't think homework is on-topic here. You don't learn if you don't solve the problem yourself.

Comment: cheers, the homework is finished mind, I just literally stumbled across a different A record for that domain that just so happened to point to an IP address not managed by Cloudflare, but by Rackspace. The IP address isn't pingable, so I'm assuming it is just an old A record.

Comment: IP addresses don't need to respond to a ping (ICMP echo request) to work.

Answer (score 0):

The IP for bcu.org.uk is owned by rackspace
The DNS for the domain bcu.org.uk is hosted by cloudflare a company offering CDN and reverse proxy solutions.
The IP of www.bcu.org.uk is owned by cloudflare which serves as a proxy for
the domain.

User Bob -> www.bcu.org.uk -> (Cloudflare DNS) -> Cloudflare Proxy IP (Internal Checks DDOS etc.) -> Real Webserver (IP hidden from User Bob)

It is possible that bcu.org.uk and www.bcu.org.uk point to the same physical machine but that would expose the real ip of www.bcu.org.uk quite easily and is therefor unlikely.

Please excuse any spelling mistakes english is not my native language